# Twitter Data - how to modify y-axis in stacked bar using plotly - R

Tags: r, twitter, bar-chart, plotly

With this dataset https://github.com/frm1789/Project_Dante2018/blob/master/cc2.csv
It shows for each day, and each hour, the n-tweets made with a particular hashtag.

- `day`: day of the week.
- `hour_only`: hour of the day.
- `n`: total of tweets for that hour.
- `nn`: total of tweets for that day.
- `n_pc`: percentage of the tweets for hour/day.

Using this code:

```
cc2 %>%
plot_ly(x = ~cc2$day, y = ~(n_pc), color = ~n_pc, hoverinfo = 'y'
        ) %>%
##add_bars(colors = rainbow) %>%
layout(barmode = "stack",
       title = 'In what moment of the day, people tweet about #Dante2018',
       xaxis = list(title = "Days of the week"),
       yaxis = list(title = "Q - Quantity of tweets")
)
```

I would like to obtain all the rows with the same space, because each space in each row represents an hour. And also, I would like to setup up the y-axis from 0 to 24.

My results by now are:
[image]

I understand that I am very close, but I don't know how to modify my graph.
Or even if the entire idea is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after something like this?

```
library(plotly)
cc2 %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~(day), y = ~(hour_only / hour_only), color = ~n_pc, hoverinfo = 'text',
          text = ~paste('Hour of the day: ', hour_only)
  ) %>%
  ##add_bars(colors = rainbow) %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack",
         title = 'In what moment of the day, people tweet about #Dante2018',
         xaxis = list(title = "Days of the week"),
         yaxis = list(title = "Q - Quantity of tweets")
  )
```

[image]

---

**Note**: You might want to rethink your y-axis label since `y` here is the time of the day, and not the quantity of tweets. Your color labelling, I believe, takes care of the percentage of tweets in a specific hour.

Comment: This solution works perfectly well. Thank you very much! I am wondering if you know how to change the title of the bar "n_pc" to something different. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/jmnlkf08yhokbh5/image2.png?dl=0]